# How can I find many-to-many relations in nest.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I try to view the document of `typeorm` (for v0.3 now). But the Nest.js application is based on v0.2.

The [document](https://typeorm.io/many-to-many-relations#loading-many-to-many-relations) said that I can use `find` method with find-option:

```js
const questions = await questionRepository.find({
    relations: {
        categories: true,
    },
})
```

But when I try, the TypeScript tell me that the `relations`' type is `string[]`. So I change it to:

```js
const questions = await questionRepository.find({
    relations: ['categories']
})
```

But raise an error:

```
Relation "categories" was not found; please check if it is correct and really exists in your entity.
```

I do not want to use `createQueryBuilder` because it uses the string and it is hard to deal with: Sometimes the original entity changes its name but TypeScript will never raise an error...

So can I use the relations on v0.2? I cannot find anything useful for this version.

Comment: Are you sure that table `categories` has  a relation with table `question`?

Comment: @orimdominic Yes, it is many-to-many relations. With `@ManyToMany`.

Comment: Can you share your entity code

Comment: share the categories & questions schemas